# MongoDB returns None even when database has data and other functions works. Using Python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So I have mongoDB database an I am trying to get data from it based on `_id`.

```py
def find_data():
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
    db = client.users_commit_hashes
    collection = db.test
    _id = ObjectId("643eef196a3a623bc8abc8ac")
    collection.find_one({"_id": _id})

print(find_data())
```

When I call my function it returns `None`. I don't know what is wrong, because all other functions that I am using works just fine only this one does not. Object ID is correct I checked it multiple times.

Comment: Test with `collection.find_one({})` to make sure it is connected where yo think it is

Comment: That also throws `None`. I have update function that is above and is connector is same as in this function also the `_id` is the same. Update function works fine.

Comment: btw does find_data return anything

Comment: @cmgchess returnes just `None`

Comment: If that empty filter also returns None, that would imply that you are not connected to the database/collection where the data is stored.

Comment: i meant shouldnt you return the data u just queried from your function like `return collection.find_one({"_id": _id})` or something like that. right now you are printing a function that returns nothing

Comment: @cmgchess that sounds like it. Thanks. Probably should get some sleep.